# Suppose $n$ is prime and $x \in Z$ satisfies $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod n.$ Prove that $x \equiv 1 \mod n$ or $x \equiv -1 \mod n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $n$ is prime and $x \in Z$ satisfies $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod n.$ Prove that $x \equiv 1 \mod n$ or $x \equiv -1 \mod n$.

So far I have done the following proof, but I am unsure how to complete it:

We will begin by explaining why $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod n$ iff $n|(x^2 - 1)$. Then use this to prove that $x \equiv 1 \mod n$ or $x \equiv -1 \mod n$.

If $x^2 \equiv 1 \mbox{ mod } n$, then $x^2 = nk +1 $, for some $k \in Z$. Therefore $nk = x^2 -1$, and $n|(x^2 -1)$.

On the other hand, if $n|(x^2 -1)$, then $nk = x^2 -1$ for some $k \in Z$, and then we can say $x^2 = nk +1$, and thus $x^2 \equiv 1 \mod n$.

From here, however I am not sure how to demonstrate that this shows $x \equiv 1 \mod n$ or $x \equiv -1 \mod n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can factor $(x^2-1)=(x+1)(x-1)$.  Since $n$ is prime, $n\mid (x^2-1)$ implies $n\mid x+1$ or $n\mid x-1$.  So $x\equiv 1$ mod $n$ or $x\equiv -1$ mod $n$.

Answer (score 2):

An essential property of primes is the following:

> If $p \mid ab$ then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.

In your case, $n \mid (x+1)(x-1)$, so $n \mid (x+1)$ or $n \mid (x-1)$.

Comment: That property is called [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma).